# python3 delete line in variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am doing a script to backup some configurations on FLEX LENOVO.

The resultat include my last command as well as one line generated by the material.
Both must be deleted.

Here is a chunk of the script.
output is a byte file containing the configuration
new_file is the variable to save the resultat in string format.

```py
output = new_connection.recv(max_buffer)
fex_backup = f"{path}/{date}_{ip}.config.txt"
new_file = open(fex_backup, 'wb')
new_file.write(output)
```

The result is:

```
show running-config
Current configuration:
!
version "8.4.14"
```

My question is how to delete the first two line with a regex by parsing the variable output before saving in a file.

If a simpler way exists, I will take it.

Comment: Have you tried split() method? Maybe output.decode("ascii").split(":")[1] will do the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```py
# Your text
output = """show running-config
Current configuration:
!
version "8.4.14"
"""

print("\n".join(output.splitlines()[2:]))
```